# How to put a notification tell me that file is encrypted after using AES ? & How to check it is the file i encrypt or not ?

Tags: java, file, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using AES symmetric encryption algorithm in java and after i encrypt file i want to put something on it to tell me it is encrypted so i can check for it is exist or not before decrypt it ?
Here is a sample of the code

```
   ` cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    jTextField3.setText(""+secretKeySpec);
    String cleartextFile = "E:\\"+dir;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\d"+dir);


    FileChannel out = fos.getChannel();
    out.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(cis), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);  `
```

Comment: `transferFrom()` isn't guaranteed to perform the entire transfer in one call. You have to loop.

Comment: @Sherif You mean you want to define a file format for encrypted files?

Comment: @SherifMostafa This is only possible if you have something uniquely recognizable in each unencrypted file too. Deciding if something is an arbitrary unencrypted or encrypted file is not possible.

Comment: @EJP transferFrom()  transferred all no need to make a loop i tried it on image and video it works fine

Comment: @ Artjom B not file format i need to make sure it is the file i encrypt before i decrypt because if i make a decryption for non encrypted file it will be damage so what i need is how to make something on the file while encrypting to make sure when decrypting it is valid

Comment: @SherifMostafa a) Believe EJP. b) It´s not possible to detect if some arbitrary file is encrypted. Everything you could do to recognize it could be there by coincidence too. If something will be damaged, you´ll need to rethink how your program works.

Comment: @deviantfan loop on what ?

Comment: @SherifMostafa On transferFrom, until the sum of return values is how many bytes you want (and that´s not `Long.MAX_VALUE`) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29